# Double-pole electric baseboard thermostat wired as single-pole?

Tags: electric-heat

I wanted to replace an old 2-pole electric baseboard thermostat with a new one.  However, when I pulled out the thermostat I was confused by the way it is wired (see photo - both red wires connected to each other, and both black wires connected to each other).  It appears as if it is wired as a 1-pole thermostat would be.  Can anyone explain why it might be wired this way?  I don't want to hook up my new digital thermostat the same way if it may damage it.  Note that in the photo I had already removed the ground connection.

[image: 2-pole thermostat with odd wiring]

Comment: Your suspicion appears to be correct, it appears to be wired Single Pole.

Comment: Years ago it was leagal to break 1 side of 240 lines, this did create a possible hazard since the other side of the circuit was still hot. Today double pole thermostats and controllers are the standard for safety.

Comment: I know for sure at least one other is wired this way, but I'll bet all 5 thermostats in the condo are wired this way.  Looks like I need to figure out which wires are what in the box, and re-wire it the right way.